# removing an item in read only listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

i have made a listbox datatemplated with button and  binded to a textbox.
i would like to be able removing one item by a tap & hold.
my probleme : an invalid operation exception pops

here is my code

Button remover = (Button)sender;

```
     fileListbox.Items.Remove(remover.Content);
```

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=Operation not supported on read-only collection.
  StackTrace:
    à System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.RemoveImpl(Object value)
    à System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.RemoveInternal(Object value)
    à System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Remove(Object value)
    à proByOrange.views.preDevis.Page1.GestureListener_Tap(Object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    à Microsoft.Phone.Controls.SafeRaise.Raise[T](EventHandler`1 eventToRaise, Object sender, GetEventArgs`1 getEventArgs)
    à Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.RaiseGestureEvent[T](Func`2 eventGetter, Func`1 argsGetter, Boolean releaseMouseCapture)
    à Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.ProcessTouchPanelEvents()
    à Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.TouchComplete()
    à Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.Touch_FrameReported(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
    à System.Windows.Input.Touch.OnTouch(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
    à MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(IntPtr target, UInt32 eventId, IntPtr coreEventArgs, UInt32 eventArgsTypeIndex)

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to remove an item from a ReadOnly collection. You can't change such a collection. As you may expect by the name you can only read such a collection, you can't change it.

You're title refers to a textbox but your code and stacktrace imply something using an ItemsSource.

If you need to be able to change what is displayed, just make the UI elements readonly and leave the backing collections writeable.

If you can show some example code we can show how to change it appropriately.

Comment: hello matt, what kind of code would u like to see ?? the xaml one ? and how can i set the collection to writable ? ty

Comment: @user569574 something that demonstrates what you're doing / the problem you're having. It can be a stripped down version of your actual code or a new project.

Answer (score 1):

If you've bound the `ListBox` to a list somewhere (in a view model would be good) by using the `ItemsSource` property as Matt suggests and your question implies, then in order to remove an item from the list, remove it from the source collection. The best approach if you are modifying the contents of the list is to use `ObservableCollection<T>`, which raises collection changed notification when the collection changes, so your UI will update automatically:

```
public ObservableCollection MyList { get; private set; }
...
// Inside an event handler or view model command handler.
this.MyList.Remove(itemToRemove);
```